# When try to insert into table i am getting QSqlError("", "Parameter count mismatch", "") here is my query

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite

```
   QSqlQuery insert_emi_query;
   insert_emi_query.prepare("INSERT INTO emi_info (emi-info_id, customer_id, down_payment, emi_start_date, emi_end_date, emi_amount, toatl_emi, intrest_rate, total_emi_amount) "
                 "VALUES(:emi-info_id, :customer_id, :down_payment, :emi_start_date, :emi_end_date, :emi_amount, :toatl_emi, :intrest_rate, :total_emi_amount)");
   insert_emi_query.bindValue(":emi-info_id",emi_id);
   insert_emi_query.bindValue(":customer_id",cutomer_id);
   insert_emi_query.bindValue(":down_payment",ui->txtEMIDownPayment->text().toInt());
   insert_emi_query.bindValue(":emi_start_date",ui->dateEMIStart->date());
   insert_emi_query.bindValue(":emi_end_date",ui->dateEMIEnd->date());
   insert_emi_query.bindValue(":emi_amount",ui->txtEMIPerMonth->text().toInt());
   insert_emi_query.bindValue(":toatl_emi",ui->spinEMI->text().toInt());
   insert_emi_query.bindValue(":intrest_rate",ui->txtEMIRate->text().toInt());
   insert_emi_query.bindValue(":total_emi_amount",ui->txtEMIAfterPayment->text().toInt());
   if(insert_emi_query.exec()){
       qDebug() << "EMI Info Added---------------------";
   }else{
       qDebug() << "EMi not inserted" << insert_emi_query.lastError();
   }
```

Comment: Can you give more information about the Schema of the table you are trying to insert into?

Comment: Good, now looks readable.

Answer (score 1):

`:emi-info_id` is not a valid [parameter name](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#varparam) (`-` is not allowed in unquoted identifiers, and parameter names cannot be quoted).

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to edit your question. May be you want to edit it yourself, using the following snippet, to improve comprehension.

1) Is the dash symbol in "emi-info_id" right? Most databases do not allow a dash in a column name.

2) May be you want to check if you have specified values for all mandatory columns of the table.

```
QSqlQuery insert_emi_query;

insert_emi_query.prepare("                                         "
"                                                                  "
"INSERT INTO emi_info (                                            "
"   emi-info_id, customer_id, down_payment, emi_start_date,        "
"   emi_end_date, emi_amount, toatl_emi, intrest_rate,             "
"   total_emi_amount)                                              "
"                                                                  "
"                                                                  "
"VALUES(                                                           "
"   :emi-info_id, :customer_id, :down_payment, :emi_start_date,    "
"   :emi_end_date, :emi_amount, :toatl_emi, :intrest_rate,         "
"   :total_emi_amount)                                             "
"                                                                  "
);

insert_emi_query.bindValue(":emi-info_id",emi_id);
insert_emi_query.bindValue(":customer_id",cutomer_id);
insert_emi_query.bindValue(":down_payment",ui->txtEMIDownPayment->text().toInt());
insert_emi_query.bindValue(":emi_start_date",ui->dateEMIStart->date());

insert_emi_query.bindValue(":emi_end_date",ui->dateEMIEnd->date());
insert_emi_query.bindValue(":emi_amount",ui->txtEMIPerMonth->text().toInt());
insert_emi_query.bindValue(":toatl_emi",ui->spinEMI->text().toInt());
insert_emi_query.bindValue(":intrest_rate",ui->txtEMIRate->text().toInt());
insert_emi_query.bindValue(":total_emi_amount",ui->txtEMIAfterPayment->text().toInt());

if(insert_emi_query.exec()) {
   qDebug() << "EMI Info Added---------------------";
}
else{
   qDebug() << "EMi not inserted" << insert_emi_query.lastError();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that column name `emi-info_id` is typo in you query. It should be emi_info_id. Because column name with `-` is invalid.

If you are using Qt5(I didn't know what is there in qt4) or above then you can get error type like

```
insert_emi_query.lastError().type()
```

In above case it should be `QSqlError::StatementError` because there is typo in name of column.